# Android and C# tcp connection sockets

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets, tcp

my question isn't about creating the connection. My question is about reading the stream in the c# code. The java android code is sending 3 parameters by `DataOutputStream`. the C# code get them all, but in different sockets. I mean if I have the array byte received it will be in 2 diffrent messagess. Let's see the code and it be clearly. 
Java code :

```
private DataOutputStream out;

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.145"); 

        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port); 

        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

// Header

                        out.writeByte(IDMessage); // example :IDMessageis is 1

                        // Data
                        out.writeDouble(LongX); // example :LongX is 35.4
                        out.writeDouble(LatY); // example :LatY is 31.5

                    out.flush();
```

and c# code reading :

```
// Data is the array byte received (byte[])

    using (memory = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    using (r = new BinaryReader(memory))
                    {
                        IDMessage = r.ReadInt32();

                        Long = r.ReadDouble();
                        Lat = r.ReadDouble();
                    }
                }
```

Again: The problem is that the massage is received in 2 different byte array. I mean 1 array will be `1,0,0,0,.....` and the other array in different massage will be `35.4,31.5,0,0,0,0,......`

Any one have any idea why it happen? Thanks. :)

Edit : by the way it the message two, in the first massage I just need to send one parameter so it work's great by the sending and reading, in the two massage it send the 1 parameter alone and in other socket the two doubles.
Edit : The proxy code :

```
            int k=0;
            byte[] byteRecived = new byte[1024];

            // Start Listeneting at the specified port 
            listenerForAndroid.Start();

            // Now the server is running and waiting for a client connection.

            sender = listenerForAndroid.AcceptSocket(); // Client Accepted

            while (IsListener)
            {
                try
                {
                    k = sender.Receive(byteRecived); // The server is resieved message . This line is get 2 other massages.

                    Header h = new Header(byteRecived);
                    message = MessageFactory.getMessage(h);
                    if (message is RequestID)
                    {
                        counterObserver ++;
                        SendIDMessage(sender,counterObserver);
                    }
                    message.DeSerialize(byteRecived);
                    message.Execute();
                }
                catch
                {

                }
```

Comment: The only thing TCP guarantees is that the bytes that are delivered will arrive in the exact same sequence in which they were sent. In particular, the bytes may be delivered with a completely different grouping, or even all of the bytes in a single group. It is up to you to accumulate incoming bytes until you have enough to do something useful with, and then to repeat the process for as long as there is still data to receive.

Comment: But why it received in 2 different massage ?

Comment: My comment already explained that. In TCP, there is no such thing as a message (and certainly no such thing as a "massage" :p ). The TCP connection is simply a stream of bytes, nothing more. Any "message" boundaries you think you've imposed simply by grouping the data while sending are _not_ guaranteed to be preserved when receiving. If you care about the boundaries, you have to embed them in the bytes themselves (e.g. delimiters, byte counts, etc.)

Comment: Okay, I got it from the previous comment but I don't understand where I wrong ? What to do for solving this question ? I trying to read in one "massage" when it sending it in two. I understand why, but how to fix it ? Please help me I'm really got crazy from this.

Comment: Impossible to offer specific advice with such a vague code example. But the basic strategy is to not try to parse a complete message until you _have_ a complete message. For example, read iteratively  from the stream until you have the 20 bytes you expect there to be in a message. If you only get 10 bytes the first time you read, then go back and read more data. Repeat until you have the 20 bytes you expected.

Comment: I have been edit the code. Please take a look.

Comment: k = sender.Receive(byteRecived); ... this line is excute two times with two different byteRecived. What mean's we have two different receive. How can I control that it will be in one recieve?

Comment: You can't. And I don't know how many other ways I can say what I've already said several times: _you have absolutely NO control over how many bytes are returned "in one receive"_. With TCP, this is by design and it is your _obligation_ to write your code to accommodate that.